# Unable to load ppt addins

Tags: powerpoint

I am unable to load a ppt-addin to my ppt. When trying to add, it is throwing in this error [See Pic].
It doesn't make any sense, as the file is indeed there in the location.

[image]

Additional details:

**Version**

[image]

**Macro Settings:**

[image]

Comment: Is this a VBA add-in, a COM add-in or an Office.js add-in? You didn't state where you placed the add-in. The correct folder for VBA add-ins is _C:\Users\YourActualUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns_.

Comment: Hi, it is a vba addin. I don't think location is the problem because I  was able to load the same addin without any dependency on location, a few months back.

Comment: @Charlie That's correct; you can browse to and load add-ins from any folder that your user profile gives you access to. John's mentioned the default folder that PPT looks in when you begin to browse for VBA add-ins and when you choose to save a file as an add-in. Sometimes we forget that we intended to use a different folder and accidentally save to the default, but that wouldn't appear to be the case here. What's changed since you were last able to load the add-in?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Sorry for late reply. As a last resort changed the name of the addin and it solved the issue. The name had numerals in it. So I am guessing that might have been the culprit but I don't know why it should fail because there was no problem earlier, loading the same addin with same name.

Comment: Well, that's certainly odd. Numerals in the name should cause no problem ordinarily. Glad you sorted it, though.